# Is Wronskian infinitely times differentiable?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

If $y_1, y_2$ are two solutions of the differential equation

$a_{0}(x)y'' + a_{1}(x)y' +a_{2}(x)y = 0$
where $a_{0},a_{1}  a_{2}$ are continuous and $a_{0}(x) \ne 0$

Then the wronskian $W$ of $y_1,y_2$ is infinitely times differentiable (True/False)

Now, this is my approach using Abel's Identity this is equal to

$W = A\text{exp}(-\displaystyle\int \dfrac{a_1(x)}{a_{0}(x)} dx)$

So, by this logic Wronskian seems to be infinite times differentiable .

Is this correct ?

Can someone please verify ?

Thank you.

Comment: Based on your exoression for $W$, I expect it won't be infinitely differentiable if the ratio $a_1/a_0$ is not differentiable. Consider $a_1(x)=|x|$ and $a_0(x)=1$.

Comment: @Spencer: Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

False.  If the $a_i$ are only continuous, there is no reason for $W$ to be differentiable more than once.

Comment: So, if $ai$ were to be differentiable , then is the claim true ? Or do we need more conditions ?

Comment: Each additional degree of differentiability of the $a_i$ gives one more for $W$.  So to ensure $W$ is infinitely differentiable, you'd want the $a_i$ infinitely differentiable.